# Is there a convention for setting variables based on arguments?

Tags: c++, conventions

Say I have a function with a flag or something:

```
void foo (Param p1, Param p2, bool setVariable)
{
    //if setVariable is true, set some bool var to true, else false
}
```

Is there a strong preference of one over the other of the following?

```
if (setVariable)
    _someClassVariable = true;
else
    _someClassVariable = false;
```

or

```
_someClassVariable = setVariable;
```

Obviously the second is less typing, but the first strikes me as more readable. Which one would be preferred?

Comment: If the argument is aptly named, the second can be just as readable. However, this is very much a question of personal preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generally prefer the second. To me, the first would be a strong warning that whoever wrote the code was barely competent at best.

That said, I'd also tend to recommend against passing a bool as a parameter as a rule. It's rarely immediately obvious what `foo(true);` vs. `foo(false);` really means. It's usually better to use an enumeration so you get `foo(do_this);` vs. `foo(do_that);`

Comment: first paragraph - my thoughts exactly.

Comment: Enums are pretty good for that, I agree. And now that I think of it, I'd probably react the same way to someone else's code if they used the first.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for the second, it is just as readable. Readability is more on the names of the variables than on the choice of both options. If the variables and parameters have good names the assignment will be natural. This is similar to returning a boolean from a function you would not do:

```
bool conditionHolds() {
    if (condition)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

(And if you are considering doing it, please rethink it)

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer the second one. If less typing isn't enough of an argument for you, also consider your co-worker's opinions. I, personally, would laugh if I saw something like

```
if (condition)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

in production code. (provided the variables are bool, and you're not using this to implement some casting mechanism).

Comment: To be fair I have seen `if(condition==true) { return true; } else { return false; }` in the field :S

Comment: I think it might have had the inverse as an `else  if` sometimes code is so bad it hurts

Answer (score 2):

The latter is much better, the if else just looks useless an introduces extra complexity both in the code and the compiler produced code gen (although PROBABLY optimised away).

I would also avoid the leading underscore notation, some of those name are reserved fro the standard library and compiler.

Comment: The underscores make me feel like I'm looking at some horrible linker make script, (shudder!).